# Project in Eclipse break when I launch it today

Tags: java, eclipse

This morning I just open Eclipse and find my project (which was working perfectly last time I worked on it and ran it) with tons of errors.

Error with package: "java.lang.Class cannot be resolved" same for java.lang.Object

I tried to add in library my JRE again so the error on package is fixed with this but now ALL other lines of my project (all my imports in each file, all my class , ...) contain an error so I don't understand 2 days ago my packages and imports were well imported into my project and everything goes well and no it's like all my project just break and now I don't find the solution to solve this ..
Please help

Hi all,
Finally I re-add a JDK and install all packages updated for eclipse and now I just have errors with my imports it seems eclipse doesn't find the imports I want I think it's because I start my project to the university and want to continue it at home on my own computer so do you know how should I add this imports and then eclipse can use them ? (on eclipse Juno 4.3)

Thanks for answers

Comment: Did you use maven in your project? If yes, use it as plug in or from command line?

Comment: mangusta I think this si the solution but how I do it correctly I don't want to totally break my work ...

I thought I just have to re-import my packages and then all errors were fix but apparently it's not working I still have all my errors with imports and classes ..

erhun I don't think I am using maven in my project.
The thing is it's my first android game so I don't know eclipse platform very well I don't really know where I can rebuild my project and re-import everything..

Comment: "the project was not build since his build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path the try building the project."

Comment: Please add more details about your working environemnt, how do you compile your code? What is the project type, you say it is an android project how you can not rebuild your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to 'Configure Build Path' and add the required libraries

Comment: I did that to add JRE library thenmy package doesn't get error anymore but now I have more errors with imports and others it's like all my code lines are broken ...

After configuring my build path what should I do to solve this ?

Comment: Can you add the code here, so i can see exactly what are those errors?

Comment: Sure I do this now but I think it's not an error from my code it's from the project which can't load package and other things I need in my project... How can I send you the project here ?

Comment: Just rollover the mouse pointer on the error code and check the errors, eclipse provides fixes for most of the error.

Comment: I have added my path but now still a problem with my imports eclipse can't find them :(

Comment: You must be missing some external libraries. Check which external libraries you need to add for those imports.

Comment: I miss the library Android classpath container but when I ask eclipse to add this library it says : "unable to get system library for this project" ... :(

Comment: It's finally okay I fix it !!! Thank you for your advices it takes me long time to fix it because I'm beginner but now I can finish my android app ! Thanks !